# Topology show X is compact

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I no the following where we can use the definition of compact to be: [image]

Comment: Note that for a discrete space, all the points $\{p\}$, where $p\in X$ are open.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** If $X$ is discrete and compact, $(\{x\})_{x\in X}$ is an open cover for $X$. Use compactness to extract a finite subcover.

And if you know that $X$ is discrete and finite, from every open cover you can extract a specific (open) subcover: $(\{x\})_{x\in X}$.